# Flask Swagger UI not able to find swagger.json

Tags: python, flask, swagger

I'm trying to run flask swagger ui but its prompting me message of No API definition found.
there is online swagger.json that i'm fetching using requests and putting it in static > swagger.json .
Can't share online swagger url as it is organisation property.

folder structure:

```
| App
    | static
           | swagger.json
    | app.py
    | requirements.txt
```

code:

```
import requests
import json
import argparse
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_swagger_ui import get_swaggerui_blueprint
from flask import Blueprint

REQUEST_API = Blueprint('request_api', __name__)
PATH = "C:/Users/swagger/api/static/swagger.json"

def get_blueprint():
    """Return the blueprint for the main app module"""
    return REQUEST_API

APP = Flask(__name__)

### swagger specific ###
SWAGGER_URL = '/swagger'
API_URL = '/static/swagger.json'

json_data = requests.get('https://url/api/swagger.json') 
data = json_data.content
with open(PATH, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)

SWAGGERUI_BLUEPRINT = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
    SWAGGER_URL,
    API_URL,
    config={
        'app_name': "API"
    }
)
APP.register_blueprint(SWAGGERUI_BLUEPRINT, url_prefix=SWAGGER_URL)
### end swagger specific ###


APP.register_blueprint(get_blueprint())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="API doc")

    PARSER.add_argument('--debug', action='store_true',
                        help="Use flask debug/dev mode with file change reloading")
    ARGS = PARSER.parse_args()

    PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))

    if ARGS.debug:
        print("Running in debug mode")
        CORS = CORS(APP)
        APP.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=PORT, debug=True)
    else:
        APP.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=PORT, debug=False)
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: `/static/swagger.json` looks like an absolute path (I don't know how it is interpreted in Windows environement) but your are writing your file at `C:/Users/swagger/api/static/swagger.json`. Maybe you mean `static/swagger.json` (without the starting slash) for `API_URL`. to prevent any consistency issue, you could use the same constant to write your file and pass it to `get_swaggerui_blueprint`

Answer (score 0):

The basic example of [flask-swagger-ui](https://pypi.org/project/flask-swagger-ui/) explicitly says that local resources are accepted. So this should work:

```
from pathlib import Path

API_URL = Path("C:/Users/swagger/api/static/swagger.json")  # maybe you need a .resolve() if Path objects are not supported
```

Comment: Didn't actually for me, but yes, anyway does not accept neither Path objects nor Windows paths objects it says. 
So one should just write the text-based path

Answer (score 0):

File structure:

```
| root
    | requirements.txt
    | swagger.json
    | main.py
```

main.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_swagger_ui import get_swaggerui_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/doc')
def doc(): return open('swagger.json').read()

API_URL = '/doc'
SWAGGER_URL = '/api/v1/docs'

swaggerui_blueprint = get_swaggerui_blueprint(SWAGGER_URL, API_URL, config={'app_name':"My App"})

app.register_blueprint(swaggerui_blueprint)

app.run()
```